# Easiest way to use a keyboard shortcut to toggle desktop icons

Tags: windows-8, desktop-icons

I've tried autohotkey, and I can't find a script that will work with windows 8 after hours of searching. Please help me find an easy way to assign a keyboard shortcut like windows F11 to toggle the visibility of the desktop icons. Thanks.

Comment: The HowToGeek has a guide on this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-turn-the-desktop-icons-on-or-off/

Comment: This is for Vista, and I specified that I have windows 8. I just tried it, and it's not working. Thanks though.

Comment: The article also says it works for Windows 7 in the second paragraph, so there was the possibility that it works for 8 as well. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

I finally realised what my mistake was with the script that I was trying to use. The following is the script that I found online:

```
F12::

    ControlGet, HWND, Hwnd,, SysListView321, ahk_class Progman
    If HWND =
        ControlGet, HWND, Hwnd,, SysListView321, ahk_class WorkerW
    If DllCall("IsWindowVisible", UInt, HWND)
        WinHide, ahk_id %HWND%
    Else
        WinShow, ahk_id %HWND%

Return
```

My mistake, was forgetting to change `F12` to `#F11`. I was confused because the description of the script said that the shortcut was Windows-F11 but the script was inconsistent. Thanks for your help though.